# Divi footer not aliging to bottom of page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, footer, custom-wordpress-pages, divi

I have a problem with my Divi footer. I want to have it at the bottom of my page but nothing is working. Im struggling for more than 2 hours and I can't find the option.

Tried custom css, fixed footer, absolute footer its not working for me.

[Here a screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyjEg.png)